# can I use more with short adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, comparison

Can I say " The girl is more short than the boy "
and when can I use more with short adjective?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it is not idiomatic, and hearers will either wonder why, or will assume that you are not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Most common adjectives have their own comparative and superlative forms : **Short, shorter, shortest - big, bigger, biggest** and so on. You only need to use **more** with adjectives that don't, for instance **more unusual** rather than 'unusualler', which isn't a proper word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *more* with short adjectives if *more* also modifies an adjective that doesn't take *-er*, as in *more silent and sad*. (You can also say *more silent and sadder*.)

There are also a few one-syllable adjectives that form their comparatives with *more* – the most common are probably *fun*, *real*, *wrong*, and *right*. The comparatives *funner*, *realer*, *wronger*, and *righter* are only used rarely, and many people will perceive them as incorrect, although they will understand them.

But aside from these exceptions, we generally use *more* only with adjectives that are two syllables and longer, and use *-er* with one-syllable adjectives.